# Proportion of rational elliptic curves of a given rank

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

This morning appeared on Arxiv the following article by Manjul Bhargava et al: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.1826.pdf, in which the authors give a lower bound for th proportion of rational elliptic curves of rank 0 or 1.
Do we know explicit values of r such that the proportion of rational elliptic curves with both the algebraic and the analytic rank equal to r is 0?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is conjectured that this is the case for any $r \geq 2$, but as far as I am aware this conjecture is wide open. This conjecture follows from conjectural distributions of Selmer groups given by Poonen and Rains, as explained in the paper you mention.